# While inside a function, how do I get its return address?

Tags: c, stack, function-pointers, memory-address

I'm looking to create a list of memory locations from which this function was called. Is this code ever correct? How could it be improved? Assume integers, long integers, and pointers are 4 bytes and char is 1 byte. Assume there are no compiler optimizations performed. Assume the function uses/sets its arguments, return value, and local variables.

```
void * CalledFromArray[ARRAY_SIZE];
int CallerRecorder(int i)
{
 int LocalVar1;
 int LocalVar2;
 CalledFromArray[i]=(void *) *( (long int *)(  (char *)&LocalVar2 + 36 )  );
 return 0;
}
```

Comment: You can get at most the _return address_ from where the callee function was called, but IMHO there is no way to get the _address_ of the calling function. Maybe shou should tell us what you are actually trying to achieve.

Comment: There's no standard way to access the call stack. Anything like this will be very implementation-dependent.

Comment: @Michael You're right, I'm looking to create a list of memory locations from which this function was called. I'll edit the question to reflect that. My question doesn't make sense right now as it stands...

Comment: Aside; `CalledFromArray[ARRAY_SIZE];` lacks a type. And why the `(long int *)` cast? Would both types be better as `void*`?

Comment: If you want to obtain all or part of the call stack, [libunwind](http://www.nongnu.org/libunwind/man/libunwind(3).html) is a good place to start.

Comment: @Weather_Vane Agreed, I'll add those changes in

Comment: While there's no standard way to do this, and attempts to try to figure this out via dodgy casts is most likely going to blow up some day, you might find platform specific extension to do this. e.g. if you're using the gcc compiler, see https://gcc.gnu.org/onlinedocs/gcc/Return-Address.html , or use existing libraries to accomplish this.

Comment: @Barmar Yes, though I still need an implementation-specific solution to my problem though. Perhaps someone could suggest one while stating their assumptions about their implementation?

Comment: If you want an implementation-specific hack, you should say which implementation.

Comment: It might help to explain why you need this information. What are you going to do with it?

Comment: Modulo the other things that are problematic with this approach (indeed even a change in compiler options can probably break it), what is the purpose of `LocalVar1`?

Comment: @Gene I pruned this function before posting it. Assume the function uses/sets its arguments, return value, and local variables.

Comment: @KeithThompson I'm debugging a large multi-threaded code base. I'd like to see when/where my instrumented function is called

Comment: @notAlex: You should add that information to the question. Most people aren't going to see it if it's just in the comments.

Comment: You will find relevant information here [**Printing Stack Frames**](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/34645611/printing-stack-frames)

Comment: Have you checked CaptureStackBackTrace ( https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/bb204633%28v=vs.85%29.aspx for windows ) or backtrace ( http://linux.die.net/man/3/backtrace for linux/osx/ios )

Answer (score 1):

I am not sure what is the real purpose behind this. But just an idea if you're using GCC.
Perhaps you could collect function names which have called your function. For this reason I would rename your function, then added one additional parameter `const char* const pFunction`, and created a macro with the original name of the function to call the new one passing `__FUNCTION__`. Then the next step would be to use `dlsym` to search for the address of the calling function.

```
#define CallerRecorder(var) CallerRecorderNew((var), __FUNCTION__)

int CallerRecorderNew(int i, const char* const pFunction)
{
    // dlsym(..., pFunction)
}
```